# translation of text and seals on painting (Poet identified: Pu Ru 溥儒)

Tags: translation, seal, poetry, calligraphy

its been in the family since the 1950's, I asked a friend but he couldn't read it. also google translate was rubbish. friend said the calligraphy was to hard.
[image: some sort of scroll painting ?]

[image]

added the very bottom bit

Comment: Thank you all so much for this

Answer (score 3):

井・飛影露走・

閒坐階前為有情

萬里碧空雲似錦

月・團扇不分明

茗函冷澀石生斑

苦竹・・・檻間

扇影生寒消月魄

・聲邊・成雲山

・・・影玉西沉

落・江上變秋音

誰知錦瑟・・然

玉露微霜正傷・

結合畫面來看，是思歸之詩。秋仲，霜降露結之日，月朧雲疏之時，少婦執團扇，捧香茗，倚坐石邊階前，是“為有情”也。至月沉日更，霜已成露，沸茶作冰，不知何處秋音自起，再添神傷。

（但是詩寫得確實不咋滴（坐了這麽久居然還沒凍死））

不過特意自題“飛鴻”、“舊王孫”，還叫“溥儒”，不得不讓人揣測“美人自喻”，“黍離麥秀”，“故國招魂”那檔子事情。

Comment: 佩服佩服，畫題沒提供還把字差不多都解出來了，草書對我來說實在是太難讀了

Comment: @droooze 我是覺得是個滿清遺老的故國之思呢。。。思歸之詩只有白天坐到晚上，哪有晚上又坐到白天的？有明寫“玉沉”，實指“日升”的影射。

Comment: 說得有道理，我找了下溥儒畫的幾幅畫，好像每兩幅畫都有什麼「飛鴻」「舊王孫」這幾個字，我以爲只是他的藝名號稱，沒想太多

Comment: @droooze 我查了查他，鈐印多有“舊王孫”、“飛鴻”。以此推測這幾句詩可能還是過分揣度了。但是舊王孫、飛鴻這兩個鈐印，確實露骨地表達自己對舊朝的懷念。也虧六三年就離世了，再多活幾年可不得安生。

Comment: 舊朝的懷念，晚上坐到白天，日升〉「光復大清」

Answer (score 2):

This is a painting by the [Qing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty) imperial descendant [Pu Ru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puru_(artist)) (溥儒). I'll leave someone else to do the calligraphy, as it's beyond my ability.

---

[image]

> 飛鴻
>
> *Flying swan*

[image]

> 舊王孫
>
> *Descendant of the former monarchs*

[image]

> 溥儒
>
> *Pu Ru*

[image]

> 明夷土

Answer (score 2):

My best guess, 1st poem is:

井梧飛影・・・

閒坐階前美有情

萬里碧空雲似錦

月・・・・・・

2nd is:

茗函冷澀石生斑

苦竹・・・・閒

扇影生・消月魄

・・・・・雲山

the 3rd one is:

・・・影玉西沉

・・江上・秋音

誰知錦瑟・・・

・・・・・・・

remaining characters are:

西山逸生詩・・・・・

Comment: That last line should start off with 西山逸士溥儒畫. Anyway I can't find this painting or its text anywhere :(

Comment: it’s worth to contact the national palace museum, the taiwan one :)